# To demonstrate motion planning of a Husky robot through dynamic environments using Gazebo, how can I introduce moving characters in Gazebo?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, gazebo, clearpath

I am working on the ClearPath Husky ROS Navigation stack and am trying to demonstrate the motion of Husky through an environment with dynamic obstacles in Gazebo.

I see that mostly such a demonstration of algorithms is done in MATLAB and Pygame in 2D and using point objects.

How can this be done in Gazebo?

Answer (score 0):

Gazebo has its own tools to simulate object dynamics. See https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=animated_box